# Data from multiple sources with unknown ids T-SQL and Azure SQL Edge

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-sql-edge

I'm trying to define the architecture of my project using Azure Iot Edge and the module Azure SQL Edge (so I can have storage and use ML), but I'm stucked in the streaming part.

I'm getting data from a factory that has several machines and each machine has several different sensors that send data at different times. Each variable I get is just identified by an ID. I receiving something like this:

| Timestamp | variableId | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07/04/2022 12:34:7.89 | abc123 | 3 |
| 07/04/2022 12:34:8 | ert456 | 45 |
| 07/04/2022 12:34:8.59 | abc123 | 5 |
| 07/04/2022 12:34:9 | uio786 | 12.67 |

I want to use the variable abc123 and uio786 to a ML model and the ert456 and uio786 to another without making a specific select for their ID, but having this definition somewhere. A dynamic select...
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-edge#input-and-output), you can use a data file as reference data for an Edge Stream Analytics job, so you could add your data needed for routing in there.

You can't do this in SQL Edge Streaming.